# Fix SDTT warning on JobPosting: "The value field is recommended."

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

On the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) I get a warning for not entering a value in the `baseSalary` property.

> The `value` field is recommended. Please provide a value if available.

However, I have added a value.

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "JobPosting",
    "hiringOrganization": "Google",
    "validThrough": "2018-12-31T00:00",
    "baseSalary": {
            "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
            "currency": "USD",
            "value": {
                    "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
                    "minValue": 40.00,
                    "maxValue": 50.00,
                    "unitText": "HOUR"
            }
    },
    "jobBenefits": "Medical, Life, Dental",
    "datePosted": "2011-10-31",
    "description": "Description: ABC Company Inc. seeks a full-time mid-level software engineer to develop in-house tools.",
    "educationRequirements": "Bachelor's Degree in Computer Science, Information Systems or related fields of study.",
    "employmentType": "Full-time",
    "experienceRequirements": "Minumum 3 years experience as a software engineer",
    "incentiveCompensation": "Performance-based annual bonus plan, project-completion bonuses",
    "industry": "Computer Software",
    "jobLocation": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "address": {
                    "@type": "PostalAddress",
                    "addressLocality": "Poole",
                    "addressRegion": "Dorset",
                    "streetAddress": "33 Holton Road",
                    "postalCode": "BH16 6LT"
            }
    },
    "occupationalCategory": "15-1132.00 Software Developers, Application",
    "qualifications": "Ability to work in a team environment with members of varying skill levels. Highly motivated. Learns quickly.",
    "responsibilities": "Design and write specifications for tools for in-house customers Build tools according to specifications",
    "salaryCurrency": "USD",
    "skills": "Web application development using Java/J2EE Web application development using Python or familiarity with dynamic programming languages",
    "specialCommitments": "VeteranCommit",
    "title": "Software Engineer",
    "workHours": "40 hours per week"
}
```

Could someone please provide a fix so the code passes the Google Structured Data Testing Tool?

Answer (score 0):

Your code violates the standard:
`baseSalary` doesn't contain something like hours, but only currency and the value or range.

Beside of this there is a inconsistency:
you write on one place:

```json
"minValue": 40.00,
"maxValue": 50.00,
"unitText": "HOUR"
```

On another place:

```json
"workHours": "40 hours per week"
```

What now? 40 hours or between 40 and 50?

Another thing: `workHours` are not for amount of working hours per week, but for typical beginning and ending of shift.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I want to display an hourly pay rate.. e.g. £40 - £50  per hour.

Comment: @user3760151 https://schema.org/DatedMoneySpecification could be the way to go: `this could represent an employee's salary over a specific period of time`